# How can I find out the result of onActivityResult from my Application class?

Tags: java, android

So I'm developing an ad mediator library and an app that uses my library could also use an in app billing api, so there could be a `startActivityForResult(...)` in one of the classes of the app that use my library and when there is a callback for `startActivityForResult`, I want to know the result. Since `onActivityResult` is called before `onActivityResumed` when I get the intent from `onActivityResumed` it is null. So I need a way to know the result of in app billing, without directly setting a listener, or changing the code directly.

this is the application class of my library:

```
public class SubApplication extends Application {
    static final String TAG = "AdMediator";


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityPreResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sub application onActivityPreResumed: " + activity.getIntent().getData());

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sub application onActivityResumed: " + activity.getIntent().getDataString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sub application onActivityPaused: " + activity.getIntent().getData());
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sub application onActivityStopped: " + activity.getIntent().getData());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the activity that uses my library looks something like this:

`AdMediator adMediator = new AdMediator();`

and somewhere in the logic of the appliation that uses my library is:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

and when there is a callback for this, I need to know the result without changing the code of the application that uses my library:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "in MainActivity onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    // my library should be notified here
}
```

Comment: Start your own `IntermediaryAdMediatorActivity` which will catch the necessary `onActivityResult` and won't actually have anything to do with the app using your library

Comment: @Shark Could you please provide a link? I searched for intermediary activity and I came up empty handed.

Comment: There is no link. What that means is, the app using your library calls some method of your library, instead of `startActivityForResult(YourLibraryActivity, 13)`, and that "some method" will start a translucent activity of it's own which can start the billing - when the billing is finished, your activity will get the `onActivityResult`, read what it needs, and can finish itself while forwarding that same result to the app's activity that started it.

Comment: If your library *needs* to be notified in the app's `onActivityResult` the only way you can get notified is to start a man-in-the-middle activity that will read what you need to be notified of, and forward the result back to the app. Because putting stuff such as "please notify my library in every `onActivityResult`" in the documentation won't do much

Comment: I'm looking for a way that doesn't require the developer who uses my library to change their app.

Comment: so... launch your own translucent activity that will receive the billing's `onActivityResult()`